# Conditional query inside the findAll parameter with nodejs sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am creating a query with the nodejs sequelize, but when I query on postman it gives an error, can you help me on how to do it?

Error: Error: Invalid value { undefined: 'test1' }

```
exports.customer_search = async (req, res, next) => {
    await Customers.findAll(
        {
            //where: { business_code: req.query.business_code }
            //[Op.like]: [{customer_name: req.query.customer} ]

            where: {
                customer_name: { [Op.like]: '%' + req.query.customer_name + '%' },
                }
        }
        )
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
                //message: "Customer list",
                result
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err,
                result: err
            })
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're sending `customer_name` as an object from your request as opposed to a string.

Make sure you set `customer_name` as the key and a string value after the `=` sign in the URL.

It should look like this

`http://localhost:3000/api/?customer_name=test1`

Comment: hi, i checked it but the endpoint points are correct. But he cannot query and sends 500 error

Comment: [endpoint address](https://ibb.co/G0RCQ7D)

[Route](https://ibb.co/cTW1jnG)

[Error](https://ibb.co/dfRLQXS)

Comment: Can you share what your route code looks like?